# Google script loop stops at first match

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to search for a similar name, not exact in google sheet. Which function is case insensitive and does not exactly match?
e.g. If my column contains names of places Delhi, New Delhi, South Delhi, North Delhi then my Search for Delhi should list all 4. However, the loop stops at the 1st match.

```
function search(e){
 var id = e.parameter.id;
  
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  for(var i = 0;i<values.length; i++){
    
    if(values[i][0] == id || values[i][1] == id ){
      i=i+2;
      
      var Airport = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(Airport).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
    }
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Id not found").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
```

Comment: You should consider some simple tutorials to learn the basics before attempting such searches.  It may be easier for you to grasp the use of Class TextFinder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function search(e) {
  var id = e.parameter.id;
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let a = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == id || values[i][1] == id) {
      a.push(values[i][2]);
    }
  }
  if(a) return ContentService.createTextOutput(a.join(',')).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Id not found").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```